# EF Core - FirstOrDefaultAsync throws Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to test ASP.NET Core Web API controllers using XUnit. I am using the DBContext directly in the controller. In production, I am using SqlServer and for testing, I am using InMemory provider. When I am testing some code which is using the EF Core `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method, the application is throwing null reference exception. The value I am looking for doesn't exist in the DB. As per my understanding, it should return NULL, it should not throw an exception.

I tried something like `where(x => x.Id = id).FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, it is also throwing the same null reference exception.

[image: Null Reference exception]

When I tried something like

```
var exist = await list.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == id);
if(!exist)
{
return NotFound();
}
var user = await list.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id);
return user;
```

It works.
Both dbcontext and users property are got values, those are not null.

[image: Immediate Window]

Please help.

Comment: what is `list` here? `IEnumerable<User>` right?
how you got this list? from context?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes, list is DbSet<User>, and it is from DbContext.

Comment: @mjwills It is 10. It is an InMemoryDatabase context, which I am using for testing. So I am hard coding the values to 10

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Here is the gist - https://gist.github.com/anuraj/6cb319eb68ee56d9bd4f29b80f8d2f9f

Comment: agree with @mjwills suggestion, need some minimal reproducible example, with such statement nd single line output, we can't identity exact scenario

Comment: Which part is null here exactly? The error should say. The context isn’t null itself?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am not able to identify which is null. Both the objects from my code got values, looks like it is thrown from framework.

Answer (score 5):

The exception is not caused by your code. I was able to reproduce it with the latest at this time EF Core 3.0 Preview 7. It happens with the in-memory provider - `FirstOrDefault[Async]` and `SingleOrDefault[Async]` methods. Does not happen with `First[Async]` or `Single[Async]`.

Anyway, the main problem here is that you are using a *preview* (beta) software, which is expected to have issues.

Simply switch to the latest stable EF Core 2 version and wait for 3.0 release before trying to use it in production code.

Comment: I am using EF Core v2.1 and got the very same issue as the OP

Comment: @M.Ruiz I doubt it is the same - this was really 3.0 preview related and wan't reproducing with the latest stable 2.x. Might be something similar though.  Consider asking own question with details about your issue.

Comment: Excuse me but I'm not asking any question, I'm stating that I have the same issue using v2.1 which is LTS, or at least that's what I thought. Cheers mate.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Using v2.2.

Comment: @Noob You are mixing EF Core specific extension method (supposed to work only with EF Core provided `IQueryable<>` implementations) with mocked implementation. I have no idea what that mocking library is doing and what EF Core expects. If the standard sync methods (`First`, `FirstOrDefault` etc.) work and Async versions fail, then I guess the problem is in mocking library implementation.